# PublicClientApplication reference not set when initialized

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to implement Office 365 using Graph and as I understand I initially need to store PublicClientApplication after sending it my application ID:

```
_clientApplication = new PublicClientApplication("MyApplicationID");
```

This statement however always throws an Object reference not set error when called. 
My application is registered on apps.dev.microsoft with a native platform. I've tried messing around with those settings, create new ones,...

Any idea what could cause it? Can it be online configuration? It didn't seem to require any particular attention on the quickstart guide...

Answer (score 1):

The `PublicClientApplication` is a class from [Microsoft.Identity.Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication?view=azure-dotnet). One of two things is happening here:

1. You don't have Microsoft.Identity.Client referenced in your project. If this is the case, you'll want to [add it from NuGet](https://preview.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/1.1.0-preview).
2. You're not including `using Microsoft.Identity.Client;` at the top of your file so it can't find the namespace. Without a `using` statement you'll need to reference the namespace explicitly in your call:

```csharp
_clientApplication = 
    new Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication("MyApplicationID");
```

Comment: It's already added to the PCL and the individual platforms:   `<package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client" version="1.1.0-preview" targetFramework="portable46-net451+win81" />` And referred with a using.

Comment: This error is telling you it can't find an object definition here. This means it can't find `PublicClientApplication` or `_clientApplication`.  You only have 3 components in play here and the 3rd is a String so it clearly isn't that.

Comment: Quite strange right? I've tried reinstalling the package but no luck. I mean I don't even get why it would ever throw this exception, it should throw it once I start trying to use `_clientApplication` so there's probably an underlying problem. I'll try to experiment with targeted profiles again.